# How to use `inSet` with tuple of columns?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

In Slick, we can use `inSet` for a single column to perform sql `IN` clause. But I couldn't figure out how I can use it with pair of columns.

PostgresQL allows the following usage of `IN`:

```sql
select * from table where (table.a, table.b) in ( values
 (1, 'foo'),
 (2, 'bar')
)
```

I thought I can do the following in slick but it doesn't compile:

```scala
TableQuery[Table].filter(
  row => (row.a, row.b) inSet Seq(
    (1, "foo"),
    (2, "bar"))
  )
```

Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you just can do it manually, writing something like:

```scala
val expectedTuples = Seq(
  (1, "foo"),
  (2, "bar"),
  (3, "baz")
)

TableQuery[Table].filter(
  row =>
    expectedTuples.map{
      case(fst, snd) => row.a === fst && row.b === snd
    }.reduce(_ || _)
)
```

This is known [feature request](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/517) in slick.

Comment: I couldn't think of reducing `Rep[Boolean]`s to combine them. Good idea. But I think this is a bit inefficient since it will always check for each tuple. In my case I have tuples in the order of thousands so I think I will go with raw sql.